# magento simple popup when create order from admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-order-create

I just want to show a simple popup in admin when create order if the customer has VAT

[image]

please help me on this

thanks

Comment: you need to used event observer for this.

Comment: can you please brief me if possible or any example code thanks